# Where do I put downloaded maps on Trackmania Turbo?

Tags: trackmania-turbo

Where do I put my downloaded Trackmania maps on Trackmania Turbo so I can play them?

Answer (score 1):

you can copy all downloaded `.zip` files into `Documents>TrackMania>Tracks>Challenges>Downlaoded`
'and then navigate to them in from the game.